# Lowest ball possession in the final match of the World Cup

Tags: football, records, world-cup

In the final match of the World Cup 2018 against Croatia, France won having [39% of possession of the ball](https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/match/300331552/#match-statistics) ([34%](https://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2018/07/15/world/world-cup/france/croatia/2166125/?ICID=HP_MS_01_01) or even [32%](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2018/jul/15/france-croatia-world-cup-final-match-report) according to other sources). In contrast, possession of the winner of other world cups have been:

- 2014: [61% for Germany](https://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2014/07/13/world/world-cup/germany/argentina/1220140/)
- 2010: [55% for Spain](https://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2010/07/11/world/world-cup/netherlands/spain/881633/)
- 2006: [51% for Italy](http://www.espn.com/soccer/matchstats?gameId=191983)
- 2002: [44% for Brazil](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport3/worldcup2002/hi/matches_wallchart/germany_v_brazil/newsid_2067000/2067939.stm)

That's pretty much all I could find online. Is 2018 the world cup where the winner had the least possession of the ball in history?

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned in [this french article](https://www.lequipe.fr/Football/Actualites/La-france-sacree-avec-une-faible-possession-historique/923126) from "lequipe", one of the best sports newspaper, it's the lowest possession during a world cup final since apparation of statistics in 1966